# Nested 'ifelse' statement returning this error: 'mult argument can only be 'first','last' or 'all''

Tags: r, nested, data.table

New to SO / R, so thank you in advance for being patient with me. I'm trying to get a simple if/else statement to work in R, that creates a column and populates with three categories for High / Medium / Low based on the values of a different column.

The error I'm getting is 'mult argument can only be 'first','last' or 'all'. I've found surprisingly little documentation on this error, and I know my issue is likely to be a simple one.

Reiterating again that I am very new to this. Thank you in advance for your help. A more efficient method too would be something I'm very open to hearing.

```
zips3[, PW_Data := ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.4 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.5), "Poop",
                                    ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.5 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.6), "Poop2",
                                           ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.6 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.7), "South", "Exclude"]
```

Comment: You should check out `dplyr::case_when`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is nothing to do with ifelse and everything to do with not matching your ( and ) properly, which means you are passing extra arguments to your data.table. The syntax is `ifelse(condition, trueresult, falseresult)` like `ifelse(1:3 < 3, TRUE, FALSE)`, not `ifelse(1:3 < 3), TRUE, FALSE)` like you have, which won't work properly at all. E.g., matching your brackets makes it work fine:

```
library(data.table)
zips3 <- data.table(pctr08zip_updated=seq(0L,10L,1L)/10)

zips3[,
  PW_Data := 
    ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.4 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.5, "Poop",
    ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.5 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.6, "Poop2",
    ifelse(pctr08zip_updated > 0.6 & pctr08zip_updated <=0.7, "South", 
    "Exclude")))
]
```

Re: a more efficient method, see `?cut` which will chop a vector into segments defined by a series of cut points and return a factor variable, which can be labelled appropriately.

```
labs <- c("Exclude","Poop","Poop2","South","Exclude")
zips3[, PW_Data_cut := labs[cut(pctr08zip_updated, c(-Inf,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,Inf))] ]
```

I specify the labels separately here since you have a duplicated output for your high and low values that are out of range. It gives the same result:

```
identical(zips3$PW_Data, zips3$PW_Data_cut)
#[1] TRUE
```